# How do I reference launch template version number in auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

How do I add a reference to the latest version number of the launch template in the auto-scaling group? The launch template and auto scaling group are in separate files as the launch template is used by other autoscaling groups as well. Can Fn::GetAtt and Ref be used here to refer to another resource located in a separate file? If so, how can I use it? The end goal is when I make an update to the launch template, the autoscaling group should automatically refer to the latest launch template.

Note - I am creating the launch template completely separate before creating the auto-scaling group. It works this way, but I would like the auto-scaling group to refer to the latest launch template. It currently defaults to version 1.

launch_template.yaml

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: testtemplate
      LaunchTemplateData:
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: >-
            arn:aws:iam::blah
        ImageId: ami-12345
        InstanceRequirements:
          InstanceGenerations:
            - current
          MemoryMiB:
            Min: 8192
          VCpuCount:
            Min: 2
            Max: 4
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - Ebs:
              VolumeSize: 16
              VolumeType: gp2
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              Encrypted: true
            DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        Monitoring:
          Enabled: true
        KeyName: testkey
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-1234
        PrivateDnsNameOptions:
          HostnameType: ip-name
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: terminate
```

autoscaling_group.yaml

```
---
Resources:
  testautoscalinggroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: test-autoscaling-group
      MaxSize: '2'
      MinSize: '1'
      DesiredCapacity: '1'
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - subnet-1234
      TargetGroupARNs: 
        - Ref: targetgroup
      MixedInstancesPolicy:
        InstancesDistribution:
          OnDemandAllocationStrategy: lowest-price
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateName: testtemplate
      Tags:
        - Key: Cluster
          Value: test
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
  dynamicscalingpolicy:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: testautoscalinggroup
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      TargetTrackingConfiguration:
        DisableScaleIn: false
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 30
  targetgroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Name: testtargetgroup
      Protocol: TCP_UDP
      Port: 53
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      VpcId: vpc-1234
```

Comment: why the `aws-cloudformation-custom-resource` tag?  I don't see anything about custom resources here

Comment: " The launch template and auto scaling group are in separate files"  are they in separate cloudformation stacks or the same cloudformation stack?

Comment: separate stacks as well.

Comment: If they were in the same stack, you could just use `Fn::GetAtt: [ LaunchTemplate, LatestVersionNumber ]`.  But since they're in different stacks, it's trickier.  Can't use a stack export because they aren't allowed to change while imported.  One technique would be to create an SSM Parameter in the stack template stack, setting the value of the parameter with the `Fn::GetAtt`, and then use that parameter as an input or dynamic source within the template stack.  However that has the drawback of requiring you to keep the stacks in sync when the parameter changes.